# How to iterate all rows and columns through a loop in MS project

Tags: vba, ms-project

Am working on Ms project file and currently am having trouble in below two areas

1) Now am trying to iterate all rows and columns through a loop
for ex:-

```
Task      ResourcesName      Start 

products    xxxx              10/3/2017

projects    yyyy              11/04/2017
```

I can get first column value(Task) name using below code

```
dim var = ActiveProject.Tasks(x + 1).Name
```

but I need to traverse to resources name and start column and I need to store all the values in variables

2) second question is I observed that in my MPP file that for some columns names are like

1. Task
2. ResourcesName
3. Start  etc

But, If I try to store the column values by using below code

```
For each oSubTasks in Activeproject.Task    
    dim var1 = oSubTasks.GetField(FieldNameToFieldConstant("Task"))    
next
```

The values are like Text1,Text2 etc

My question is that how can i get the actual displayed values from MPP file columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that perhaps you are using vb.net rather than vba since you state this works:

```
dim var = ActiveProject.Tasks(x + 1).Name
```

If that is the case, then make sure you use [Early Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx) so you have [IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) ([more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion)) when you are writing your code. That way you declare `oSubTask As MSProject.Task` and when you type `oSubTask` followed by a period you get a drop-down list of the properties and methods.

Secondly, you state that you want to get the "actual displayed values". For string fields such as task Name and Resource Names, there is no difference between what is stored and what is displayed. However, for date fields this is not the case. To get a task's Start date as a date value, use: `oSubTask.Start`. But to get the string representation of the date as displayed, use: `oSubTask.GetField(pjTaskStart)`.

Here is a VBA sample:

```
Dim oSubTask As Task
Dim taskName As String
Dim taskRes As String
Dim taskStart As Date
Dim formattedStart As String

For Each oSubTask In ActiveProject.Tasks
    taskName = oSubTask.Name
    taskRes = oSubTask.ResourceNames
    taskStart = oSubTask.Start
    ' to see how the date is displayed, use GetField
    formattedStart = oSubTask.GetField(pjTaskStart)

    ' do something with these values
Next
```

Comment: First of all Thank you Rachel Hettinger, But in my case Displayed value and Backend values are not same For Ex :- Front end Value will be  Taskname but when I read from code it gives me Text1,Text2 as values but my question is how can i get the displayed values because i need to compare when my source File

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how to loop through your Ms-Project tasks, and read the `Task.Name` and `Task.Start` from them (into an array).

```
Dim oSubTasks As Task
Dim oName(1000) As Variant
Dim oStart(1000) As Date
Dim i As Long

i = 1
For Each oSubTasks In Activeproject.Tasks
    oName(i) = oSubTasks.Name
    oStart(i) = oSubTasks.Start
    i = i + 1
Next oSubTasks
```

Comment: @vineeth vp have you tried my code in my answer above ? is it working for you as you intended ?